# How to make PDF from GitHub open in new tab?

Tags: html, anchor

I have a pdf file in a GitHub repo and an anchor tag that points to it (`<a href="https://github..../file.pdf>link</a>`) and when I click it, i download the file automatically.

How to make it open the PDF in a new tab, before downloading it (to the file system, just downloading it within the browser)?

I've tried adding `target="_tab"` and `target="_blank"` to the anchor, but all got me the same results?

Is it achieable using just HTML, or I need to use an external JavaScript library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add `target="..."` whatsoever. I guess you're pointing to the wrong URL. GitHub provides access to the raw file through this URL pattern:

```
//github.com/<account>/<repo>/raw/<branch>/path/to/file.pdf
```

Note the `raw` part in the URL. Check if you got your URL right. A functional example:

```
<a href="//github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/raw/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld.pdf">Test PDF</a>
```

You can test it [clicking this link](//github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/raw/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld.pdf). A dialog will open asking you to specify where to download it.

Comment: This is no longer available. Is there still a solution in 2019?